# I unable to use Amazon web services s3 uploader in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-web-services

I have developed a app for using aws services, but i could not.I have "access key" and "secret key".But when go for s3 uploader i found error "No such bucket" and you are not sing up. I think , when i created the account i was not complete the "payment method" process.
So aws not provide the test mode . I am confuse please suggest me right way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for iOS. Building off the suggestions from Brad:

- Make sure you can access the S3 console from AWS website. This will ensure you have an active and valid account
- Make sure you have copied the access and secret keys correctly into the S3_Uploader sample application `Constants.h` correctly
- The sample creates a unique name based on your access key.  If this is failing for some reason you can update `Constants.m` in the sample to use your own custom name (or use a bucket that you've already created via the console)

Comment: Thank you Bob. I think i was going on wrong direction.I am unable to access s3 console from aws website.it stop me on payement method step.SO without given credit card info, i can not use s3 uploader service.So any way to check aws services without payement or in test mode like authorized.net

Comment: @user2024885 Unfortunately not. However, AWS offers a "free tier" for the first year of an account which should mean that your card should not be charged for small test cases.  http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have an active AWS account.

Do you have one? Can you access your bucket from a regular PC? I am guessing you don't. Make sure you can access your account and bucket from a regular dekstop before doing it on your iPhone. You need to go into the management console and create an S3 bucket, if not -you will get that error. (Either that, you are trying to access the wrong one).

Comment: Thanks Brad but i am using this code to create bucket.
 _s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];

        // Create the picture bucket.
        
        createBucketRequest = [[[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
       
                       
       S3CreateBucketResponse *createBucketResponse = [_s3 createBucket:createBucketRequest];

        if(createBucketResponse.error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", createBucketResponse.error);
        }
This is correct or not.